# Is it possible monitoring at real time all the syscall under linux?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

For example, in a linux-machine there are so many process.
Each one is able to use a syscall, but usually few are used.
Well, there is a tool or a manner to show when a syscall is used and which is the process associated?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptrace

Comment: ptrace() is a system call by itself, not a tool.

Comment: I don't know how to trace svc for all processes (system wide)  but, `strace` is my favorite tool to trace a specific process.

Comment: @favoretti: yes. if you click on the link you'll see that's the very first sentence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use various tools, like `strace`, `ltrace` and many other, although I'm not sure you want to trace all processes at the same time.

Normally you'd attach to one process of interest and follow its system calls.

Comment: Well, I can use strace for one process.
And what about if an user is creating a new file, can I see the syscall related about his creation with this method?

Comment: it's not the user, but a *process*, that's really creating that file. if you're connected to *that* process, then, yes... if you only want to monitor the FS, there are other tools for that.

Comment: Yes, my goal is monitoring the FS in real time mode, for specific files and not process.
So, I think about the syscall because are the basic instruction that the kernel run.

Comment: Then you can use `lnotify`, or otherwise some more fancy stuff, like, for instance, splunk FS change monitor (http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Data/Monitorchangestoyourfilesystem) :)

Comment: @user840718 then you should use systemtap and oprofile, which can trace and profile the entire system, not just one process like strace does.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linux kernel audit subsystem.

For example, to see all syscalls made by a program called sshd (pid - 12345):

```
# auditctl -a entry,always -S all -F pid=12345
```